# Nested JSON Transformation to insert into SQL Table - Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql, json, rest, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have connected to a REST API and the data is structured in a nested JSON format that requires some transformation before I can insert into a SQL table. I am trying to use Azure Data Factory (Copy into) to facilitate the transformation.

Each UserID is an Object, so when I try to map the fields, it gives me an error that I have duplicate field mappings.
[see screenshot of mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3YMR.png)

I do not know how to trim off the unnecessary data. This is what it looks like:

```
 {
    "count": 216,
    "results": [
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18603444"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18603297"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18603298"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18603445"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "16407315"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18636176"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18588630"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18588941"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18603301"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18603302"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18603303"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18588634"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18722305"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18603446"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18604710"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18624916"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18625925"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18603447"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18603448"
        },
        {
            "key": "users",
            "id": "18603305"
        }
    ],
    "users": {
        "18603444": {
            "full_name": "",
            "photo_path": "",
            "email_address": "",
            "headline": "",
            "generic": false,
            "disabled": false,
            "update_whitelist": [
                "full_name",
                "headline",
                "email_address",
                "external_reference",
                "linkedin_url",
                "bio",
                "website",
                "company_name",
                "address1",
                "address2",
                "city",
                "state",
                "zip"
            ],
            "account_id": "",
            "id": "18603444"
        },
  "18603302": {
            "full_name": "",
            "photo_path": "",
            "email_address": "",
            "headline": "",
            "generic": false,
            "disabled": false,
            "update_whitelist": [
                "full_name",
                "headline",
                "email_address",
                "external_reference",
                "linkedin_url",
                "bio",
                "website",
                "company_name",
                "address1",
                "address2",
                "city",
                "state",
                "zip"
            ],
            "account_id": "7600865",
            "id": "18603302"
        },
  "18603303": {
            "full_name": "",
            "photo_path": ",
            "email_address": "",
            "headline": "",
            "generic": false,
            "disabled": false,
            "update_whitelist": [
                "full_name",
                "headline",
                "email_address",
                "external_reference",
                "linkedin_url",
                "bio",
                "website",
                "company_name",
                "address1",
                "address2",
                "city",
                "state",
                "zip"
            ],
            "account_id": "7600865",
            "id": "18603303"
        },
    "meta": {
        "count": 216,
        "page_count": 11,
        "page_number": 1,
        "page_size": 20
    }}
```

Each user is structured with their ID and their respective data. I want to remove the first part with the count and results and the last part with the meta and ONLY keep the data in each ID object. I think i can delete those two pieces in the mapping of the Copy into step, but I am not sure the best practice.

How do I do this with Azure Data Factory and SQL? Or should I use an Azure Function? I am not allowed to use python or any other scripting (if it is possible). Can someone please assist?

Answer (score 0):

Add a data flow activity to your pipeline. In the data flow, add a REST source and then a Select transformation. In the Select transformation, there is a mapping panel. In there, remove the JSON properties you wish to discard.

Comment: I think you are on to something, but could you help explain further in the mapping panel?

Comment: It appears you have answered this same question on another forum, I overlooked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/813462/how-to-flatten-complex-nested-json-structure-in-ad.html

I will give this a try, but the OP never answered it worked

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample procedure for the transformation of Nested JSON to SQL DB

Create a linked service to the REST API.
[image]

Attched dataset as the source in Copy activity.
[image]

Create Linked Service to SQL DB as sink.
[image]
[image]

Dataset of SQL database attached at the sink to copy activity.
[image]

In the Mapping, Import the schema from the data remove the unnecessary fields by selecting and delete the columns.
[image]

Result we get as per the expected in SQL DB with required data from the Nested JSON.
[image]

Comment: I apologize I should have put in the original post that each userid is an object so when I try to do what you have here i get an error that there are duplicate mappings. I edited to post and added a screenshot to highlight this

Comment: I have shared in the 6th screenshot to manage the unnecessary data.